# Random diagonal matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a random diagonal matrix with size n such that each element in the diagonal entries has 50% chance of being -1 and 50% chance of being 1. Is there any advice for this?

```
import numpy as np
diagonal_entries = np.random.randint(low = -1, high = 1, size = n)
D = np.diag(diagonal_entries)
```

However, the problem is that `np.random.randint includes 0 as the value too. I only want -1 and 1, excluding 0.

Comment: @CIsForCookies Please see the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.random.choice` to sample a vector

```
import numpy as np
n=100
vec=np.random.choice([-1,1],n)
mat=np.diag(vec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a few NumPy routines for a concise routine doing this:

```
def random_diagonal(n, proba_minus=0):
    diagonal = np.ones(n)
    diagonal[np.random.random(size=n) < proba_minus] = -1
    return np.diagflat(diagonal)
```

The random routine allows you to define the probability of having "-1" and the routine `np.diagflat` creates a diagonal matrix from its diagonal. Both operations above are vectorized but for large sizes you need of course to know that there is a temporary array for the boolean mask.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
import numpy as np

diagonal_entries = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 2, size = 4)
print diagonal_entries
# i*2-1 will map [0,1] -> [2*0-1 == -1, 2*1-1 == 1] == [-1,1]
modified = [i*2-1 for i in diagonal_entries] 
D = np.diag(modified)
print D
```

I used the same function with a little modification on the results to suite your `[-1,1]` needs.

My *2nd* option would be this `modified = [1 if i == 1 else -1 for i in diagonal_entries]`